# When adding GWT into classpath, junit test failed with NoSuchMethodError, why?

Tags: eclipse, gwt, junit, classpath

I've got a project which uses GWT.
I use maven to manage dependencies, so gwt is automatically added.
I have several junit tests that run correctly when I right click on my test folder and launch as Junit test.

Now, I transform my project into gwt project using the google plugin eclipse (right click, properties, enable gwt).

When I do it, it automatically add gwt into build path (it is normally not needed because I've already got it in my maven dependencies, but gpe seems to need it).

I rerun my junit tests (using eclipse) and a NoSuchMethodError (and I'm sure that the incriminated method exists) comes with a lot of tests.

But if I run my tests using maven (mvn test), all tests success !

I use GWT 2.3.0, Junit 4.8.2, Eclipse Indigo

Why adding gwt in my classpath (via gpe) can cause my junit tests to failed (only in eclipse junit runner) ? And how to fix it ?

Comment: FYI, GPE still uses the m2e 0.12 nature naming (org.maven....), rather than the m2e 1.0 one (org.eclipse....), so it actually doesn't detect this is a Maven project. See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6606

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found the solution :

Run configuration > my junit config > classpath

here, I up maven dependencies before my project folder.

After that, all runs like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

See this [GWT FAQ entry](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq.html#gwt_in_eclipse_for_java_ee) (step #3).

> 3 . If your project uses the Apache Tomcat library, ensure that the GWT SDK library is above it on your project's classpath (project properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export). Otherwise, you may get a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when launching your application in hosted/development mode.

Comment: Hum, that was not the problem because the problem is when I run Junit, but when I try what you say, my code do not compile anymore. I found the error was I use cup for syntaxix parser and GWT also used it ! I must find a way to force the use of my cup dependency and not the gwt one during the test.